# python opencv - what is the best way to use video input to an image path interface api

Tags: python, opencv

I have an api take img_path as input as it use `cv2.imread()` to load image.

```
def detect(net, classes, img_path, CONF_THRESH = 0.8, NMS_THRESH = 0.3):
    outputs = []
    im = cv2.imread(img_path)
    ......
    ......
```

Now I want to create a small tool to directly load video and call the api function.However, while the cap.read() is done. I can't directly pass the image object into the api function.

```
def detect_video(net, classes, video, CONF_THRESH = 0.8, NMS_THRESH =0.3):
    """detect an input video"""
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video')
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return None
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # try to call the api function
```

What the best way to do so that I don't have to change the api function? My idea is to imwrite the video capture image and reload it again. but this seems stupid and slow.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass a frame as argument to your api detect function, save it first and then call the api function as usual

```
img_path = 'image.jpg'
...
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite(img_path, frame)

# and now try to call the api function
detect(net, classes, img_path, CONF_THRESH = 0.8, NMS_THRESH = 0.3)
```

Comment: thats exactly what my solution. I'm trying to seek other solution without save a video.